# Restoring Postgres db dump on Greenplum

Tags: postgresql

I Have set up a Greenplum db with two segments on AWS.
I have a Postgres database  SQL dump and I would like to use that dum to recreate the database on Greenplum. 
The only options I have seen in the Greenplum documentation is restoring to an existing db or restoring from another Greenplum set up with the same number of segments.
Does anyone have an idea of how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured to just do it like Postgres.
Create the database you want to restore, create the roles from that dB if they don't exist in Greenplum and then run the restore

```
psql -U <username> -d <dbname> -1 -f <filename>.sql
```